# SmoothScroll Offset

Tags: smooth-scrolling

Apologies, I realise that similar questions have been asked on here, but I'm a coding noob attempting to build my first website. Basically, I'd like to offset my SmootScroll target to avoid my nav-bar obscuring content. Here's what my code looks like:

```js
// Scroll
function InitScroll() {
  $('body').smoothScroll({ 
    delegateSelector: 'nav a',
    speed: 2000
    
  });
}

// Fixed Navigation
function initFixedNav() {  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $("#navigation").removeClass("top-nav").addClass("fix-nav");
    } 
    else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
      $("#navigation").removeClass("fix-nav").addClass("top-nav");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I think you are using a jQuery addon which provides your smoothScroll function, it may have an option for offset. Can you add information about the smoothScroll function and when initFixedNav is called? Perhaps you can manually use [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) with behaviour: smooth, if you are willing not to use the current smoothScroll

Comment: Aha! I'm an idiot. You're completely correct. I was using the Jquery-Smooth-Scroll plugin. Just put -70 in the offset setting and it worked perfectly! Thanks for your help though. Probably would've taken me a lot longer to spot that obvious solution otherwise!